Is It Okay to Scale up Principal Component Analysis Loadings to Fill the Plotting Region When Plotting Principal Component Analysis Scores
I have the following plot, where I've plotted principal component analysis scores.

I overlaid the loadings in the plotting region, but they're all very short and you can't see the loadings nor their labels.
Is it okay to scale the loadings up by a constant so they are actually visible and so they take up more of the plotting region, or is it not appropriate?

Are you trying to create a biplot manually?  Does Positioning the arrows on a PCA biplot provides an answer for your question?
